# React (Material UI) - MakeStyles with switch

Tags: javascript

So I have a button thats suppose to change the backgroundcolor depending on a variable (*props.status*), which is an int.

I can understand that its possible to swap between two values e.g. using something like `backgroundColor: props.status ? 'red' : 'blue'`, but what if I have many colors?
Kinda assumed something like this would work, but it doesn't.

```
backgroundColor: (() =>
      {
        switch (props.status)
        {
          case 0:
            return 'red'
          case 1:
            return 'red'
          default:
            break;
        }
      })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute the function that you just declared:

```
(() => {
     //...
})() // note the last pair of parentheses
```

This pattern is called [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)